# Magento Fetching Cart Items

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, quote

I have items in cart. But it returns empty array when fetching them. I don't know what is the problem. I used following code for getting the number of items in cart and it gives 0.But in my site I have items in the cart.

```
$totalItems = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount();
echo $totalItems;

$session= Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
foreach($session->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item)
{
   $productid = $item->getProductId();
   $productsku = $item->getSku();
   $productname = $item->getName();
   $productqty = $item->getQty();
   echo $productid;
}
```

I hope someone will help on this issue.

Comment: checkout will give you current session cart item..

Comment: yes.. In my site i have items in cart..

Comment: please try this cdoe: `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCount()`

Comment: it gives me a blank page..@AmitBera

Comment: try with checout car single to object .. `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getItemsCount()` ..

Comment: it gives a fatel error `Fatel error:Call to a member function getItemsCount() on a non-object` @AmitBera

Comment: sorry mistake `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getQuote()->getItemsCount() `

Comment: again fatel error @AmitBera

Comment: are you getting product id from checkout session

Comment: @AmitBera No man .. i am just getting the blank page error...

Answer (score 2):

```
$cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
$items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();

  foreach ($items as $item) {
       $itemId = $item->getItemId();
       $itemCount=$item->getName();
  }
```

Try this code

Comment: I also tried this code...

Comment: how do we get only visible (parent) items?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that someone has changed the database query (to fetch cart items).
For example: added `GROUP BY`

and then see the class

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::_getSelectCountSql(), _buildClearSelect()
```

can be solved as follows:

copy file from

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php
```

to

```
app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php
```

and add to function `_buildClearSelect` before `return $select;`:

```
$select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
```

Comment: Thanks @Neklo.com It's really an informative... I have changed the code as you post..But same blankpage error

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($cartItems as $item){
    $productId = $item->getProductId();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Anshu Mishra... I also checked this code...gives same empty array

Answer (score 0):

try this code:-
To get your cart object (in session) :

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
```

Then, to get the list of items in the cart :

```
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
```

Then, to get the count for each item :

```
foreach ($cartItems as $item)
{
echo $item->getQty();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ashvin Monpara actually i am getting blank page...I used this code too...